# Pandas Dataframe - Mysql select from table where condition in <A column from Dataframe>

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column which is a set of `user ids`. I would like to run a query on `mysql` based on this column values like :

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ( 'COLUMN IN DATAFRAME' )
```

How could I do this.

Answer (score 2):

To create your query you could do something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['abc', 'bce'], columns=['users'])
df
>>>   users
>>> 0   abc
>>> 1   bce

query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in (%s)" % ','.join(df['users'])
>>> 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in (abc,bce)'
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in ('%s')" % "','".join(df['users'])
>>> "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in ('abc','bce')"
```

Comment: Here it put all the column names in the "IN" clause of the query. But what I am looking for is something like this.

print df['users']
>>> abc
>>> def 
>>> ghi
>>> jkl

and my query should look like 

"select * from users where id in ('abc','def','ghi','jkl')"

Comment: would you be able to help me with this please.

Comment: @Aravindh I edited the anwser. Is that what you wanted ?