# Pulling partial data from a sqlite database using python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a huge database (~70 gigabytes) all stored in a sql table.

I cannot pull the whole database into Spyder due to memory issues, but I only need a select portion of that sql table anyways.

I have a data frame of 576 rows/elements that have an ID that correlates to an ID in the 70 gig table.

Is there a way to pull in only the data that have matching IDs from the SQL table?

This should allow for the table to be small enough for Spyder to handle plus it is the only data I need in the end so it would take care of narrowing the desired data.

I realize this is a bad question for Stack, but I am more so curious if it possible to do this pull in python without pulling the whole table in in the first place.

I have no issues finding the data once the table is in Spyder, but I have not run into this issue yet and I am new to python with SQL.

When I try to search on one ID let alone the 576, the search takes a very long time.

```
Events = pd.read_sql('SELECT SystemID FROM Events WHERE SystemID = 14237 ', conn)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Dataframe - Mysql select from table where condition in <A column from Dataframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344162/pandas-dataframe-mysql-select-from-table-where-condition-in-a-column-from-dat)

Comment: is is for mysql but the principal apply to sqllite as well